# No Calendar package is imported

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

When trying to run the following script:

```
import matplotlib as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

I exeperience the following error:

```
C:\Users\raja\PycharmProjects\Project_test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/raja/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/testing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/raja/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib as plt
  File "C:\Users\raja\PycharmProjects\Project_test\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    import urllib.request
  File "C:\Users\raja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "C:\Users\raja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\raja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Users\raja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "C:\Users\raja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "C:\Users\raja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "C:\Users\raja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "C:\Users\raja\.PyCharmCE2018.2\config\scratches\calendar.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tkcalendar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkcalendar'
```

Why? Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide us the full code of the script you're trying to execute? In the code snippet you provided there is no actual line date = calendar.datetime.date

Comment: Did you name your file `calendar.py`?

Comment: No , It was just named as testing.py

Comment: Thats what my question is there no line in my code "date = calendar.datetime.date". Whatever I posted completes my full program.

Comment: Could you provide the full log of the error you're getting?

Comment: Posted the full log

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. there was a different python program I named it as Calendar.py :(. I have deleted that file from "config/scratches/" and it has fixed the issue.

Also I have deleted the two versions of Tkcalendar installed